# marbles and boxes permutations

Tags: permutations

In how many ways can five marbles can be dropped in six different boxes? Case (1) marbles are identical Case (2) marbles are distinct. I know this belongs to permutation and I don't know which formula I should adopt

Answer (score 1):

If the marbles are identical, then we can use [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) to obtain
$$
{n+k-1\choose k-1}={5+6-1\choose 6-1}=252.
$$
If they are distinct, then the number of ways is given by
$$
k^n=6^5=7776.
$$